# Perl defining a pattern for a variable to follow

Tags: perl, variables, design-patterns

If you define `my $top = (0 .. 100)` you get each number 1,2,3,4...100 but how can I define $top to only produce 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, ... 100? Thanks

Comment: You mean `my @top = (...)`, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I run my perl script it currently prints a sentence  with a different number in it each time (so 100 sentences each with a number 1...100) but instead I want 50 sentences with numbers 0, 2.5, 5... up to 100

Comment: you're not sure about what? That the code you're showing is incorrect and Qtax's code is? Show your real code please...

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings; #Always use these!
open (MYFILE, '>script2.txt');
my $world = 1;
for my @top = (0 .. 100) {
    for my @left = (0 .. 100) {
         print MYFILE "\#world$world \{
    background: url(/images/1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
    height: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    top: $top\%;
    left: $left\%;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
   \}


   \}"; 
  $world++;
    }
}
close (MYFILE);` I just need @top to give values of 0, 2.5, 5.. 100 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3 .. 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@top = map { 2.5 * $_ } 0 .. 40;
```

Comment: `0 .. int(100 / 2.5)`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @numbers = ( 0 .. 40 );
my @top = map { $_ * 5 / 2 } @numbers;

print Dumper \@top;
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.pl 
$VAR1 = [
          '0',
          '2.5',
          '5',
          '7.5',
          ...
          '95',
          '97.5',
          '100'
        ];
```