# Perl script making a pattern in variables

Tags: perl, variables

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings; #Always use these!
open (MYFILE, '>script2.txt');
my $world = 1;
for my $top (1 .. 100) {
    for my $left (1 .. 100) {
         print MYFILE "\#world$world \{
                background: url(/images/1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
                float: left;
                width: 1%;
                height: 2%;
                position: absolute;
                top: $top\%;
                left: $left\%;
                z-index: -1;
                margin-top: -10px;
                margin-left: -10px;
            \}

            \#world$world:hover \{
                background-position: 0 -20px;
                cursor: pointer;
            \}"; 
        $world++;
    }
}
close (MYFILE);
```

Currently this perl script generates 10000 results (100 top x 100 left) but **how can I modify it so that $top produces 0, 2.5, 5...100 instead of 0, 1, 2, ...100 and $left produces 0, 1.25, 2.5, ... 100 instead of 0, 1, 2, ... 100**

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl defining a pattern for a variable to follow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783837/perl-defining-a-pattern-for-a-variable-to-follow)

Comment: @Alex => the two are related, but this is clearly a different use case that begs a different answer (`map` to generate a list vs C-style `for` for fine-grained iteration control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl's `foreach` loop is useful in many cases, but when you need advanced control over the increment, the C-style loop is the right tool:

```
for (my $top = 0; $top <= 100; $top += 2.5) {...}
```

`$left` should be easy enough to figure out.

The [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) manual page contains more information about the different styles of loops, and keywords related to their control.

Finally, modern code tends to use the three argument form of `open` along with a lexical file handle.  Change your `open` line to:

```
open my $file, '>', 'script2.txt' or die $!;
```

And then replace `MYFILE` with `$file` in the rest of the code.  There are a variety of reasons for this, which include error checking, preventing file handle clobbering, automatic closing...  A search here on SO should provide the details.

---

As ysth points out, to avoid any compound errors with floats, you can write it this way:

```
my $low  = 0;
my $high = 100;
my $step = 2.5;

my $reps = int (($high - $low) / $step);
for my $i (0 .. $reps) {
    my $top = $i * $step;
    ...
}
```

you could wrap that up in a function:

```
sub range {
   my ($low, $high, $step) = @_;
   map {$low + $_ * $step} 0 .. int (($high - $low) / $step)
}
```

and then it is as easy as:

```
for my $top (range 0 => 100, +2.5) {...}
```

Comment: This works only so long as what you're adding is an exactly representable floating point number; don't try something like `for (my $top = 0; $top <= 88; $top += 2.2) {...}`